# Updating the rolling window value in pandas based on an existing column

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a df with two columns. 
The first column has historical prices of stocks and the second column represents time intervals calculated based on the `df.index` (the index has datetime values).

I want to calculate the rolling mean of the stock prices based on the second column which has different values (0,1,2,3,4).
e.g.
The first rolling mean can be `df['Price'].rolling(0).mean()`, the second `df['Price'].rolling(2).mean()`, the third `df['Price'].rolling(1).mean()` and so on....

Is there a quick way in terms of runtime of applying rolling mean in this case?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvF7c.png)

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post a sample of your data so we can reproduce it. Otherwise, why can't you just iterate through your column and change the values of the rolling window?

Comment: I agree with @Tabbakhh but I wanted to add... There is a difference between "quick" in terms of terse code and "quick" in terms of runtime.  Which do you mean?